# How to replace Hash in Link

Tags: jquery, fragment-identifier

I want to add the hash of the url to the href attribute of a navigation:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/bla">Bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="/bli">Bli</a></li>
  <li ><a href="/blu">Blu</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have this code:

```
  $(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
      console.log(location.hash);
      $("a").attr('href', function(_, href){
        return href + window.location.hash
      });
  });
  if (window.location.hash) {
      $(window).trigger('hashchange')
  }
```

Now when I click on a submenu or enter the url by hand with the hash the menu gets updated like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/bla#hashVlaue">Bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="/bli#hashVlaue">Bli</a></li>
  <li ><a href="/blu#hashVlaue">Blu</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is working. But now if I click on the submenu again the hash is appended and not replaced. Since the page is not reloaded when clicking on the submenu the links start to look like this:

```
<a href="/blu#hashOne#hashTwo#Three#Four">Blu</a>
```

I just want one hash and if there is already one it should get replaced. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your problem exactly. But this is what you need I guess `return href.split("#")[0] + window.location.hash`

Comment: replace you `return href + window.location.hash` line in `haschange` trigger to the above

Comment: jup that's it :D gosh. can you write it as an answer

Comment: Cool. Glad to know it helped :)

Comment: give it an upvote and make it green :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always appending to `href` in your code. Check the line `href + window.location.hash` in `hashchange` callback. That's why it is always appending to the previous value. What you need is

```
return href.split("#")[0] + window.location.hash
```

Cheers :)